# Should this smart contract function be marked nonReentrant?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin

Should this function be marked as nonReentrant or is it overkill?

```
function sendEthToTokenOwner(uint256 _tokenId) external payable nonReentrant {
        address _tokenOwner = ownerOf(_tokenId);
        require(msg.sender != _tokenOwner, "Sender can't be owner");

        uint256 _price = tokenIdToPrice[_tokenId];
        require(msg.value == _price, "Please submit the correct amount of ether");


        (bool success, ) = payable(_tokenOwner).call{value: _price}("");
        require(success, "Eth cannot be transferred");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular snippet doesn't require a reentrancy protection because the `sendEthToTokenOwner()` function simply acts as a "transfer proxy". Performing a validation, and then redirecting the `msg.value` to the token owner.

If you were transferring out amount larger than `msg.value` or an amount independent on `msg.value`, then you might need a reentrancy protection (depending on other context).

Comment: Thanks so much! That is what I was thinking but just wanted confirmation.

Comment: What if the contract takes a percentage of msg.value

`uint256 fee = _price / 25;`

and then for the transfer `(bool success, ) = payable(_tokenOwner).call{value: _price - fee}("");`

I assume it would still hold true that nonReentrant is not needed

Comment: @jwarshack Correct. Because the amount is always smaller than `msg.value`.